# Junit4 execution order in inheritance

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am using JUnit4. I am trying to run tests in specific order. In individual classes the method order is as expected because of the `@FixedMethodOrder` annotation. But when using inheritance the order is not enforced. I want my `TestClassA` to be able-to run individually and also when using inheritance I want the tests to be executed in order.

TestClassA:

```
@FixedMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestClassA {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //do something
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        //test to be run first
    }

}
```

TestClassB:

```
@FixedMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestClassB extends TestClassA {

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        //test to be run after TestA in parentclass
    }

}
```

Even after adding `FixedMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`, `testB` is running first.

I want to enforce order execution when running `TestClassB` to run `testB()` after `testA()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no other way. I have create a test suite which executes in order.

Answer (score 0):

To run tests in fixed order, you can add [@OrderWith](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/OrderWith.html) (since JUnit 4.13) annotation to your test class.

> When a test class is annotated with @OrderWith or extends a class annotated with @OrderWith, JUnit will order the tests in the test class (and child test classes, if any) using the ordering defined by the Ordering class.

This can be applied for both - parent (`TestClassA`) and child (`TestClassB`) classes. You also have to specify ordering type. In your case it should be [Alphanumeric](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Alphanumeric.html) order.

Adding `@OrderWith(Alphanumeric.class)` before test class will cause the tests to run in alphanumeric order.